# Process for Facebook iOS SDK deprecations

Tags: ios, facebook, api, sdk, deprecated

I'm an SDK maker which has bundled the Facebook iOS SDK (version 3.6 from July 24, 2013). I'd like to understand Facebook's SDK deprecation policy so that I have advanced notice and can update my product accordingly. Where can I find/subscribe to this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the details of the new V2.0 API can be found in the Changelog and Upgrade guides:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading/

The version of the API as it was before last April 30 will be available until April 30 2015.

The new V2.0 will be available for at least two more years. To be precise: from the moment when a new version of the API is introduced, the current (thus V2.0) will be supported for two more years.

Within the same version there will be no breaking changes to core functionalities.

In the Changelog you can read a lot about the new permissions, and which are removed. Basically, all `friends_*` permissions are removed. Furthermore, your app needs to be reviewed when it uses other permissions than `public_profile`, `email` and `user_friends` (which now returns only the list of friends that also use your app).

You can read more on the reviewing process here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Answer (score 2):

The best I have found is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading/ which gives details of each release. Often new SDK versions will contain features which are announced at launch so I don't know how much advance warning you will get. In version 3.1 a feature is to protect agains breaking changes server side and I remember getting several messages in the Facebook developer area to update apps at this point so I guess you will just have to watch out for changes as they come. That said, I think versions 3.1+ remain supported, from which I would infer that they deliberately support older versions, so you should not have too much of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a facebook developer, I am unaware of any advance notice "push" notifications from facebook about new releases or future releases unfortunately.  You basically will hear about it first via the media and then it will appear on the developers.facebook.com website.  There is probably little they could do about this without putting all developers under non-disclosure.  That is sort of the reality we are all operating under by placing your product dependent on, or on top of, another companies product.  We have had experience here personally with that for years under Microsoft so we are use to it.  Unfortunately, you just have to educate your end customers of this fact.  Some will understand.